# Why ios device take to much time to connect to my wireless wifi

Tags: 16.04, networking

Android Ddevice takes only 3 seconds but IOS Device takes more than 1 miniute.
WiFi configuration below for 2.4GHZ:

```
interface=wlp4s0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
country_code=US
hw_mode=g
ssid=demo
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
channel=6
auth_algs=3
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=********
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wmm_enabled=1
wme_enabled=1
ht_capab=HT40+
dtim_period=3
preamble=1
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211d=1
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
```

Comment: Is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: yes. my ubuntu server and i have wireless card

Comment: Avoid TKIP (and UKIP)

Comment: remove wpa_pairwise=TKIP from configuration file still not working